# find common values of a vector that belong to different levels of a factor of another vector

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider the following `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1);x <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 5, replace=TRUE)
y <- c(2,1,1,3,4)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

`df` looks like that:

```
x y
A 2
A 1
B 1
B 3
A 4
```

I would like to have the common values in `df$y` that have different letters(levels) for the factor `df$x`. In this dummy data set the answer would be rows 2 and 3. Could please someone provide me the code to apply in a larger dataset case ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a count of the occurrences of `y` to `df`, then filter on counts greater than 1 and extract `unique` records:

```
df %>% left_join(
  df %>% count(
    y
  ),
  by = 'y'
) %>% filter(
  n > 1
) %>% select(
  -n
) %>% unique()
```

This yields

```
  x y
1 A 1
2 B 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  filter(uniqueN(x) > 1)
```